# Development laptop for Visual Studio and SQL servert

Tags: laptop

My work machine is currently 3 years old and despite a few upgrades is really starting to show its age.

Our corporate IT people want to give us laptops with 8gb of RAM and I5 dual core processors with <500gb HDD.

I think that we really need more than this.  The product I work on has 5 windows services, a web front end using a combination of ASP.Net, Javascript and even some VBScript.  Then a c#, vb.net mid layer and then a SQL Server 2012 backend.

Now on our development machines, we need to be able to have SQL server 2012 enterprise, Visual Studio 2015 and a web browser as an absolute minimum.

I think we need a minimum of 16gb preferably 32gb and Quad core processors, with SSD's at least for OS and applications.

What laptops/specs would people suggest ?

Ben

Answer (score 1):

If your it department is open to getting custom built laptops then I would recommend you get a laptop from digital storm. They custom build computers. I have a digital storm laptop and it can handle pretty much any programming work load better than most workstations. As for specs I do not think you need 32gb of RAM. I think 16gb should do. I do not know how big your sql server database is but you should be able to get away with 16gb of ram. I think for the CPU you should get a nice solid Intel i7 6700k. I know that is a desktop processor but they do offer them in laptops. You probably don't need a big GPU unless you use GPU computing but I doubt you do so i would recommend you just use the Intel CPUs onboard graphics. For storage I would recommend you get an ssd for your boot drive and a fast mechanical data drive. If your sql database is big then I would recommend that you get big 512gb ssd for your data drive so that you can have your sql database on your data drive. If you cannot get a custom built laptop then I would recommend you get a ASUS gaming laptop as those laptops are usually pretty high speced or you could even get an Alienware if you could fork over that kind of money.